# Replace multi-line text content of DIV tag in WKWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, wkwebview

Using `evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:` on `WKWebView`, I can replace a single line of text in a DIV element but how can I replace multiple lines of innerHTML?

e.g.

`<div id="MyContent"><hr>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<br><p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<hr></div>`

`<div id="MyContent">Arbitrary multi-line html goes here to replace above inner html...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the entire HTML content of the element.

`document.getElementById("MyContent").innerHTML = "New<br />Text";`